# Maven ignored maven archiver

Tags: java, maven

I'm using maven-jar-plugin in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>com.example.Manager</mainClass>
                                    <classpathPrefix>dependency-jar/</classpathPrefix>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I can see in logs that maven execute it:

```
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: example.jar
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: jar}]
```

but it don't put main class to MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: romkazanova
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_65
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

i don't understand why. I work with Idea.

Comment: Did you try to run maven with the debug switch? (mvn --debug or mvn -X)

Comment: No, i didn't. Thanks. This question has answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the configuration in a pluginManagement area cause the maven-jar-plugin is already bound to the build life-cycle

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.example.Manager</mainClass>
                <classpathPrefix>dependency-jar/</classpathPrefix>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

The problem you have is that the execution you have defined means to have a supplemental execution as the log output shows and not change the configuration of the existing execution within the [life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html).
Furthermore you seemed to be running on Maven 2 instead of Maven 3 and you should update as soon as possible because [Maven 2 has been defined EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

You can of course add the version of maven-jar-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile manually by prompt: mvn compile
or try:  mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@khmarbaise is wrong in his definition of [PluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management). According to the definition in Maven documentation, PluginManagement is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. In your pom.xml you have no needs to keep the PluginManagement node.

You only have to change the location of your configuration node from execution level to plugin level. You can see that @khmarbaise did that too.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.example.Manager</mainClass>
                <classpathPrefix>dependency-jar/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Furthermore you don't have to keep the executions node anymore because maven-jar-plugin is already bound to the build life-cycle as @khmarbaise mentioned it.

Comment: If i use the pluginManagement to change the configuration of a plugin which is already defined in the life cycle and that's exactly what is needed. Otherwise you will add an other execution to your build which is wrong. This is based on the logging output what happened.

Comment: You add an other execution only if you explicitly define one with the execution node with a unique id. Otherwise you only override the default configuration of the plugin and only for that project. Both solutions work great but pluginManagement should be used in parent projects where you will customize your plugins for a group of projects.


A good example of what I mean is documented [here](http://i-proving.com/2009/01/13/managing-your-plugins-as-distinct-from-pluginmanagement/) and Michael Buckley explain in his comment exactly my point.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is a difference. The maven-assembly-plugin does not have any binding to a life cycle by default whereas the maven-jar-plugin has one. Furthermore it's bound to the life cylce by the super pom in maven. Apart from that the usage of the id only works correct if you use the correct id. In your example you define a different id which results in a second execution of the maven-jar-plugin which is *wrong*. So you would create a pom which runs maven-jar-plugin twice times. The soltuion with pluginManagement is simpler and less error prone.